# How to generate random integers with multiple ranges?

Tags: python, random, integer

I've run into confusion in generating X amount of random integers from different sets of (a,b). For example, I would like to generate 5 random integers coming from (1,5), (9,15),and (21,27). My code generates 5 random integers but only between 21 and 27 and not from the other two. Ideally I'd like to see something like 1,4,13,22,25 instead of 21,21,25,24,27.

My code:

```
from random import randint
n = 0
while n < 5:
    n += 1
    for i in (randint(1,5),randint(9,15),randint(21,27)):
        x = i
    print i
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not ideal but it works.

First it gets random numbers from all ranges and next it selects (randomly) one value.

```
from random import randint, choice

for _ in range(5):
    print(choice([randint(1,5),randint(9,15),randint(21,27)]))
```

As Blender said - cleaner version - first it selects (randomly) one range and later it gets random value from this range.

```
from random import randint, choice

for _ in range(5):
    r = choice([(1,5),(9,15),(21,27)])
    print(randint(*r))
```

Comment: `random.randint(*random.choice([(1, 5), (9, 15), (21, 27)]))` is a little clearer.

Comment: @Blender I was working on this version too, but you are faster :)

Comment: @Blender: When dealing with ranges of unequal length, this solution is biased towards shorter ranges. See my answer to see what I mean.

Answer (score 9):

This is an interesting question; it becomes interesting when you realize that to achieve true randomness, the probability of picking a particular range must be weighed by the length of that range.

#### Ranges of Equal Length:

If the three ranges are of equal length, say range(0, 10), range(20, 30) and range(40, 50); then, to pick a single random number, we may do the following:

1. Pick a range at random.
2. Pick a random number from that range.

#### Ranges of Unequal Length:

Now, consider three of unequally sized ranges, say range(0, 2), range(4, 6) and range(10, 100);

The third range is much larger than the first two. If we employ the same strategy we employed in dealing with equally long ranges, we will be biased towards picking numbers from the first two ranges.

In order to pick truly random numbers from the three unequally long ranges, there are two strategies.

**Strategy 1: Using probability**

The probability of picking a range should be such that the probability of picking a number remains the same. We could accomplish this by weighing down the probability of piking shorter ranges.

However, instead of computing probability weights; there's a better solution. See Strategy 2.

**Strategy 2: Merging the ranges**

We could simply merge the three ranges into a single single range. Then, randomly pick a number from the merged range. It's simple:

```
import random;
def randomPicker(howMany, *ranges):
    mergedRange = reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, ranges);
    ans = [];
    for i in range(howMany):
        ans.append(random.choice(mergedRange));
    return ans;
```

**Let's see it in action:**

```
>>> randomPicker(5, range(0, 10), range(15, 20), range(40, 60));
[47, 50, 4, 50, 16]
>>> randomPicker(5, range(0, 10), range(70, 90), range(40, 60));
[0, 9, 55, 46, 44]
>>> randomPicker(5, range(0, 10), range(40, 60));
[50, 43, 7, 42, 4]
>>>
```

An added benefit of `randomPicker` is that it can deal with any number of ranges.

Answer (score 5):

```
import itertools, random
nums = list(itertools.chain(
            range(1,5),
            range(9,15),
            range(21,27)))
random.choices(nums, k=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in (randint(1,5),randint(9,15),randint(21,27)):
    print i
```

This foor loop will generate 3 random numbers one from the first range supplied, another for second range and last one for last range and prints every one on output.
Yours print is out of the foor loop and prints only the last random number from the last range given.

Answer (score 0):

for non repeated numbers:

```
from random import randint, choice

randoms = []
counter = 0    
while True:
   new_random = (choice([randint(1,5),randint(9,15),randint(21,27)]))
   if new_random not in randoms:
      randoms.append(new_random)
      counter += 1
   if counter == 5 :
      break
print randoms
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some interesting answers here, though I think this problem can be solved with a bit less code, even if it is a little bit less readable.

The basic idea here is that you have a fixed number of choices so you can essentially have one range to do the job and then plot the result to the ranges you want. Or if you want to consider it another way, create a function `f(x) -> y` that boils down to the same thing.

```
from random import randint

for i in xrange(5):
    n = randint(1,19)
    if n > 12:
        print(n + 8)
    elif n > 5:
        print(n + 3)
    else:
        print(n)
```

Or, with a function:

```
from random import randint

def plot_to_ranges(n):
    if n > 12:
        return n + 8
    elif n > 5:
        return n + 3
    else:
        return n

for i in xrange(5):
    n = randint(1,19)
    print(plot_to_ranges(n))
```

If you're using Python 3.x, you should change `xrange` to `range`.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to Sumukh Barve's answer:

**Strategy 3: choose a member of the ranges without concatenating ranges**

This approach sums the length of the specified ranges. It then produces a random integer within that range. Then it adds to that integer depending on where it is relative to the ranges.

*Example:* If the ranges are (1,3) and (5,9), where ranges are inclusive. Summing the length of all ranges gives 3+4=7. We then create a random integer between 1 and 7 (or 0 and 6). Lets say we get 2, we choose the 2nd item from 1st range. If we get a 5, we choose 2nd item from 2nd range.

```
def randint_within_ranges(ranges):
    """ranges is a list of tuples, where each tuple is a range. E.g. [(0, 2), (4, 6), (10, 100)]. 
    Ranges must be non-overlapping. 
    Ranges are inclusive (e.g. can return 4 or 6).
    Returns a random int anywhere in any of those ranges. 
    (In this example, high probability will be from (10,100) range.)
    """
    #in case ranges aren't ordered, sort them now. Lowest first, e.g. [(0, 2), (4, 6), (10, 100)]
    ranges = sorted(ranges, key=min)
    #print('ranges',ranges)
    total_range_size = sum([abs(range_[1]-range_[0])+1 for range_ in ranges])
    #print('total_range_size',total_range_size)
    lowest_range_start = min([min(range_) for range_ in ranges])
    #print('lowest_range_start',lowest_range_start)
    randint = random.randint(0, total_range_size-1) 
    #print('randint',randint)
    randint += lowest_range_start
    #print('randint',randint)

    #add the gaps
    for i in range(len(ranges)-1):
        if randint > max(ranges[i]):
            randint += (min(ranges[i+1])-max(ranges[i])-1)#gaps[i]
        
    return randint

print(  randint_within_ranges([ (4, 6), (-300, -290), (285,289), (10, 15), (48,53), (85,91)])  )
```

You can test that this only returns numbers within the ranges using the following. Ranges are inclusive of both bounds.

```
randints = set()
for i in range(1000): 
    randints.add(randint_within_ranges([ (4, 6), (-300, -290), (285,289), (10, 15), (48,53), (85,91)]))
print(len(randints), sorted(list(randints)))
```