# Find and replace numbers in list that are within a certain range of one another

Tags: python

Beginner here, so the answer will probably be very obvious (and the edited code hopefully better than this spaghetti code of mine)...

I have a list of five numbers.

```
my_list = [-197, -198, -193, -87, -192]
```

I need to find all numbers that are within a range of 10 of one another. I.e. -197, -198, -193, and -192 all fit within that category.

I need to replace these culprit numbers with other numbers.

Here is my attempted code to accomplish this:

```
from random import randint, choice

my_list = [-197, -198, -193, -87, -192]

n = len(my_list)
for i in range(n):
    for y in my_list[i+1:]:
        if abs(my_list[i] - y) <= 10: 
            mylist[i] = randint(-275, 275)
```

However (!), sometimes (and understandably so), get a result like this:

```
my_list = [-110, -110, -64, -87, -192]
```

-110 and -110 are still within a range of 10 of one another (in this case, exactly identical).

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: So if a number is within 10 of *any* number in the list you want to replace with it with a random number?

Comment: I think you need to work on how you choose the random number. For the moment you simple pick a random int. You should at the very least make sure (with a while loop?) that the chosen number is not within 10 of the first number.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the new replacement number might be within 10 of any of the earlier numbers. The obvious way to handle that is to check the new number against all of the earlier numbers.

This means you need another loop, over all of the earlier numbers. This is almost the same as your loop over `my_list[i+1:]`, except for the added problem that `my_list[:i-1]` will do the wrong thing when `i` is 0.

And you need a second loop around that, because you need to keep trying until you find an acceptable value.

To avoid nesting two more levels to the right until we barely have room to fit anything on the screen, let's refactor that into a function:

```
def tooclose(lst, n):
    for val in lst:
        if abs(val - n) <= 10:
            return True
    return False

for i in range(n):
    for y in my_list[i+1:]:
        if abs(my_list[i] - y) <= 10: 
            while True:
                newval = randint(-275, 275)
                if i==0 or not tooclose(my_list[:i-1]. newval):
                    break
            my_list[i] = newval
```

Comment: I mean, this works, but there's gotta be a better way than nested loops. Nested loops hurt my soul

Comment: I think that a better way to solve this problem is be smarter about how you're picking the new random numbers.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Yes, but this is the smallest change to the OP's existing code, and something the OP is likely to understand. Giving them a random distribution algorithm with a grad-school-level paper to back it up and telling them to code it up probably wouldn't be very helpful, would it?

Comment: I honestly don't think it'd be that hard though. All you would need to is pass multiple ranges to the randint function, which is done nicely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730396/python-how-to-generate-random-integers-with-multiple-ranges)

Comment: @RushabhMehta The way _I'd_ probably solve this is to download or write an interval-set library built around a tree, then try to fit each `[x-10,x+10]` into that set without overlap, and pick new numbers from a random distribution over the empty space in the set. But I don't want to try to explain that to someone asking this question. But if you want to, you can write a separate answer.

Comment: Yea that's what I was thinking, but you really don't need to build/download a library for it. But I understand not wanting to be too advanced.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @abarnert. I will try to learn and understand the more advanced strategies as well

Answer (score 1):

You do something like this

```
my_list = [-197, -198, -193, -87, -192]
for i,(p,n) in enumerate(zip(my_list, my_list[1:])):
    if abs(p-n) <= 10:
        my_list[i+1] = randint(*choice([(-275,p-10), (p+10, 275)]))

print (my_list)
# [-197, -242, -193, -87, -192]
```

Or the almost equivalent one-liner

```
from itertools import accumulate
list(accumulate(my_list, lambda p,n: n if abs(p-n)>10 else randint(*choice([(-275,p-10), (p+10, 275)])) ))
# [-197, 131, -193, -87, -192]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll expand upon @abarnet's answer by improving his replacement function. What it does is maintains a list of all acceptable results for randint and chooses a random value from it. After choosing a value, it updates the list to remove all values within ten of the newly chosen value.

In your case, your list would contain the integers from -275 to 275, and then you would need to take out integers within 10 of any integer in your list. Then, to select new values, use the function. `howmany` allows you to choose how many integers you want.

```
import random
def randpick(howmany, acceptablelist):
    a = []
    for i in range(howmany):
        a.append(random.choice(acceptablelist))
        acceptablelist = list(set(acceptablelist)-set(range(a[-1]-10,a[-1]+11)))
    return (a, acceptablelist)
```