# How do you sample K integers from multiple ranges simultaneously?

Tags: python

I can draw K samples from each range as,

```
K = 5
ranges = [[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]]

for r in ranges:
    np.random.randint(r[0], r[1], K)
```

I'd like to do this without a loop (for/while) since I have to draw K samples from several thousand ranges.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730396/python-how-to-generate-random-integers-with-multiple-ranges) question is solving a different problem. Thanks

Comment: When you state _without a loop_, you mean that you don't want to use a `for` loop?

Comment: Wha's wrong with having a loop? (In other words, what the *actual* problem you're trying to solve?)

Comment: Do you want `k` integers from *each* range, or a total of `k` integers from the ranges combined?  Unclear on the expected output.

Comment: For people unfamiliar with NumPy: the reason we try to avoid Python-level loops in NumPy is because they're extremely slow compared to C-level loops over the unboxed data.

Comment: Updated post to answer/clarify your questions

Comment: How big is the LCM of _b_-_a_, _d_-_c_, *etc.*?