# A random integer between specific values excluding 0

Tags: python, math, random, integer, zero

I have to generate a random integer `i` between a chosen minimum and chosen maximum value, which I have written as follows:

```
min = -10
max = 10
i = random.randint(min, max)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to exclude the number zero.

I need to exclude 0 because later on I'll be dividing min/max, so min can't be zero and max can't be as well (cause you'll get a zero modulo error).

Comment: Either re-roll the random variable or just choose 9 as the upper limit and treat a 0 as a 10

Comment: @luk2302 i was thinking of 2 options: 1. changing the 0 to another random number in case the generated number is 0      or 2. using a while loop with something like while integer i != 0,....  would you know how i could write down the first or second code?

Comment: Similar question: [How to generate random integers with multiple ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730396/how-to-generate-random-integers-with-multiple-ranges)

Comment: @mkrieger1 i dont wanna generate multiple ranges but thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes, the ranges -10 to -1 and 1 to 10!

Comment: Oh yeah but i read the question and didnt see a similarity really. i just wanted to exclude a number but i already have the question, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You could pick from -10 to 9 and then increase non-negative picks by 1:

```
min = -10
max = 10
i = random.randint(min, max - 1)
i += i >= 0
```

Or an implementation of @luk2302's suggestion, again picking from -10 to 9 but then replacing 0 with 10:

```
min = -10
max = 10
i = random.randint(min, max - 1) or max
```

Could also use `randrange`:

```
min = -10
max = 10
i = random.randrange(min, max) or max
```

Comment: i'm just trying to understand the code; what would max-1 do? cause i need max as 10.

Comment: @AnonymousRU It reduces the initial pick range. And then the adjustments make it exactly what you want.

Comment: would i be able to do this with a while loop? something like: while integer i != 0,...... or maybe making sure the code changes min or max in case the generated integer is 0? thanks for helping by the way:)

Comment: @AnonymousRU Why would you want to do that? What's the point of ensuring something that's already sure?

Comment: im new to python which means idk anything about initial pick ranges and all that. were being taught about while loops and conditions so i have to implement that theory into my code.

Comment: @AnonymousRU Well, sure, add that loop if you want to. It's just 100% pointless.

Answer (score 0):

For a small range, I would just enumerate the valid choices and choose among them:

```
x = list(range(min_value, max_value + 1))
x.remove(0)
i = random.choice(x)
```

As the range increases, the chance of picking 0 decreases, and thus so does the amortized cost of simply rerolling if you do choose 0:

```
while True:
    i = randint(min_value, max_value)
    if i:
        break
```

Comment: i wrote down the min and the max as -10 and 10 while theyre actually bigger in my code. the thing is that theres still a chance of min and max being zero, which will stop the code when it breaks. i just want all the numbers between min and max without zero.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

First is very simple. If u get a 0, generate another number until you get one which is not zero.

```
import random
min = -10
max = 10
i = random.randint(min, max)
while i == 0:
    i = random.randint(min, max)
```

Another way is to generate a list of possible values and then use random.choice

```
import random
min = -10
max = 10
possible_values = [num for num in range(min, max+1) if num!=0]
i = random.choice(possible_values)
```

Yet another way is to do what @luk2302 suggested

```
import random
min = -10
max = 10
i = random.randint(min, max - 1) or max
```

There are also other ways if you would like to explore.

Comment: If I was able to help you solve your problem, can you please mark this as the correct answer? Would mean a lot!

Comment: Sure, how do i do that? I'm new to this.

Comment: There is a green tick-mark to the left of this answer. Just click that!

Comment: @don't talk code. If I did help him I deserve that.

Comment: Cause he just said my code worked for him and that he understood it. Didnt see him say that to someone else

Comment: you helped 'her' so i'll make sure i mark it as answered by you :) i was wondering if i could private message u to ask some other questions?

Comment: Yeah! You are most welcome.

Comment: Even if that were true it wouldn't justify doing that in such a way.

Comment: @AnonymousRU The approach you like, the first one, is the least efficient (although with this particular range, not by much).

Comment: @pjs how would it be the least efficient? it got rid of the zero for me which was the goal

Comment: @AnonymousRU It uses a technique called [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling), where you keep trying until you get an acceptable result. By definition rejection sampling can involve multiple attempts, each of which requires additional work.  The other answers provided here all yield a correct/acceptable result on the first try. In this case the probability of rejecting is 1/21, so the expected number of attempts is 21/20 = 1.05, but there are problems where rejection techniques can be awful.

Comment: @AnonymousRU An example of a really bad rejection sampling technique is sorting a list by random shuffling. Check whether the values are in ascending order, and if not shuffle again.  This will in theory eventually achieve your goal of getting a sorted list, but it will take essentially forever for even moderate length lists - the expected number of attempts is `n` factorial for a list of `n` distinct values. A good algorithm is one which efficiently achieves your goal.

Comment: @pjs well since i'll be using progessively larger numbers in my code, which will make the odds of the randomly generated number to be 0 slimmer each time. and since my code isnt that long, it doesnt matter if it needs multiple attempts. would you be willing to look at my last added question? :)

Comment: @AnonymousRU The point is that if there's a solution that gives the answer in 1 step, and another that requires more than 1 step on average, and cost per step is equivalent in both cases, why would you opt for the latter?

Comment: @pjs because of the requirements of the homework - i cant use code we havent had introduced at class. thats why :)

Comment: @AnonymousRU And you haven't yet covered generating the range up to 9 and using `if x >= 0: x += 1` or `if x == 0: x = 10`? Call me dubious.

Comment: I generated the range of course using randint from the random module. The code shown in the answer isnt the entire code, just the code i had a question about. It's fixed.